# Add "View Product" button below add to cart button in WooCommerce archives pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront

Most of the articles on the internet are about **How to remove / replace the "view product" or "read more" button.** 
I couldn't find something related to allowing both buttons working together.

I am interested in having both buttons working in parallel ( at the same time ).
The first button to be displayed should be "**View product**" (to be opened on the same page) then underneath "**Add to Cart**"

At the moment, my store only displays the **Add to cart** button.
I am using Storefront theme ( + custom child theme ).

Would anyone be so kind and tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`** action hook, to add your custom button linked to the product *(except variable and grouped product types)*:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_a_custom_button', 5 );
function add_a_custom_button() {
    global $product;

    // Not for variable and grouped products that doesn't have an "add to cart" button
    if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) return;

    // Output the custom button linked to the product
    echo '<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <a class="button custom-button" href="' . esc_attr( $product->get_permalink() ) . '">' . __('View product') . '</a>
    </div>';
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and still perfectly works on WooCommerce 3.7.x *(with last storefront theme)*:

[image: on shop page]

---

Embedding your styles *(related to author comments)*:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_button_styles', 9999 );
function custom_button_styles() {
    if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ):

    // The styles
    ?>
    <style>
        .button.custom-button { background-color: white !important;
            color: black !important; border: 2px solid #4CAF50 !important; }
        .button.custom-button:hover { background-color: black !important;
            color: white !important; border: 2px solid black !important; }
    </style>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: amazing, it works. Thank you so much ! Another question, is it possible to edit the background color and the text color of this button alone? thanks

Comment: as well, I observed that there is quite a gap in between the 2 buttons, can this distance be reduced? thanks

Comment: thank you, the system doesn't allow me to post a new question ( new account ) , besides this original question was down-voted.

Comment: so I added this in style.css ( in the child theme ): custom-button {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50; /* Green */
} 
However, nothing shows up

Comment: il ne fonctionne pas. I'm thinking if there is a problem with the class name of the button. Would it be possible to name this new custom button for example .custom-button1  ? something like this .

Comment: @NoiTrade88 I have updated my answer adding a function for styling the buttons… I have tested on storefront theme and it works…