# Add product URL button below product in WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I add a button that says 'See Details' below my products in WooCommerce?

[Here is a link](http://www.gadgetgogo.co.uk/all-gadgets/) to the page I would like to add it to.

Issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990116/add-view-product-button-bellow-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-archives-page) but it doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: Please remove this line  "if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) return;" and than check, you are using variable product and which function you are using from reference link it's now allowing to add it.

Comment: Of course! Thank you for pointing that out Jogi Mehul, I appreciate your help (and thank you to @LoicTheAztec for the original post).

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal function of wordpress

```
get_permalink( $product_id );
```

check the documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

Also check this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70171/given-the-id-of-a-product-in-woocommerce-how-can-i-get-its-url)

Comment: Thanks Abdallah, I don't know php very well so having the full code mentioned in the other comments really helped.

Comment: You may also find this helpful, @Zak, for figuring out where you want to hook the function you'll create: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/