# Add New “View Product” button below add to cart button in WooCommerce archives pages

Tags: woocommerce

The answer code the *"[Add "View Product" button below add to cart button in WooCommerce archives pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990116/add-view-product-button-below-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-archives-pages) creates a new button but **above** the "Add to Cart" button.

I would like to create the "View Button" **below** the "Add to cart Button" any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong, this code works perfectly! This is because your theme (or yourself) is making related customizations. See [`add_action` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) documentation and [WooCommerce `content-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/content-product.php) template file

Comment: [Try this](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-remove-add-cart-add-view-product-loop/) It may help you.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, the code works on single-product.php but not on archive-product.php. 

I quite a newbie hence may be i have missed something or not able to explain properly. 

thanks in advance