# How to add View Product Detail Button Link Beside “Add To Cart” Button In WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The *"[Add "View Product" button below add to cart button in WooCommerce archives pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990116/add-view-product-button-below-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-archives-pages/46990670#46990670)"* answer code allows to display an additional "View Product" button below add to cart button on archive pages.

How to get this additional button **to be displayed beside** add to cart button (not below)?

[image: Image here !]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the follows code snippets in your active theme's functions.php -

```
add_action('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_a_custom_button', 99, 3 );
function add_a_custom_button( $add_to_cart_button, $product, $args = array() ) {
    if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) return $add_to_cart_button;
    $custom_button = '<a class="button primary is-outline mb-0 is-small" style="margin-left: 5px !important;" href="' . esc_attr( $product->get_permalink() ) . '">' . __('DETAIL PRODUCT') . '</a>';
    return $add_to_cart_button . $custom_button;
}
```

Comment: @ClaimJohn, I just updated my code snippet for your theme. I think it should work now. Just replace the previous one with above.

Comment: it working but not display inline bro how to solve this problem !! thanks

Comment: Can you send me a link with the applied code. So I can check

Comment: @ClaimJohn, as I can see from your previous site link, it's display button in inline. Can you show me any screen shot that exactly you want.

Comment: i want to display like that

Comment: @ClaimJohn I just added inline style in custom anchor and updated the above code. Please check it. Is it exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Need to add CSS to make them both on the place:
The div you added (better not to use inline CSS:

```
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
```

The "Add to cart" button:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 49%;
margin-left: 2%;
```

Use id for your added button, and also for the add to cart button. (see image below).

A better solution, but a bit harder to implement will be to wrap both in a div and use flex CSS

[image]

Comment: sorry i'm wrong i have edited my question ! please help me solve thanks

Comment: If you can send me a message with URL I will be able to check

Answer (score 0):

I think your template changes the hooks order. You can be more aggressive and add your button through this filter:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_my_custom_button', 20, 3);
function add_my_custom_button($html, $product, $args){
    if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) return;
    $html .= '<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <a class="button custom-button" href="' . esc_attr( $product->get_permalink() ) . '">' . __('DETAIL PRODUCT') . '</a>
    </div>';
return $html;
}
```

Comment: i want both buttons display inline bro please help me solve !

Comment: `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function `

Comment: `Stack trace:
#0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): add_my_custom_button('<div class="add...', Object(WC_Product_Simple))
#1 wp-includes/plugin.php(208): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<div class="add...', Array)
#2 wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/woocommerce/structure-wc-product-box.php(186): apply_filters('woocommerce_loo...', '<div class="add...', Object(WC_Product_Simple))
#3 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): flatsome_woocommerce_shop_loop_button('')
#4 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_fil`